# Can't update datefield to null

Tags: django

cant insert and update datefield to null

> err
>   ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

```
`class StudentUserMedicalRecord(models.Model):
     ImmnunBCGDateFirstDose=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     ImmnunBCGDateSecondDose=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     ImmununBCGDateThirdDose=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     ImmnunBCGDateBooster1=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     ImmnunBCGDateBooster2 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
       suser = '{0.Student_Users}'
    return suser.format(self)
 //my html
     <td><input type='date' name='firstdate'  /></td>
     <td><input type='date' name='seconddate'  /></td>
     <td><input type='date' name='thirddate'  /></td>
     <td><input type='date' name='firstbooster'  /></td>
     <td><input type='date' name='secondbooster'  /></td>
//my views
     first = request.POST['firstdate']
     second = request.POST['seconddate']
     third = request.POST['thirddate']
     booster = request.POST['firstbooster']
     secondbooster = request.POST['secondbooster']
       V_insert_data = StudentUserMedicalRecord(
          ImmnunBCGDateFirstDose=first,
          ImmnunBCGDateSecondDose=second,
          ImmununBCGDateThirdDose=third,
          ImmnunBCGDateBooster1=booster,
          ImmnunBCGDateBooster2=secondbooster,
     )
      V_insert_data.save()
```

Comment: You set it by `None`/`NULL` to leave the data out of the POST request, and thus then get it with `request.POST.get('firstdate')`. But you better use a `ModelForm` for that.

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: Would also encourage you to read the django docs on `ModelForm`s to improve your code. In the meantime you could also work around the empty string problem by using `first = request.POST['firstdate'] or None`, etc. to set empty values to `None` instead of empty strings.